# Confusion over wording of a question of arithmetic progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

[image]

In the highlighted part part is 15,000 given An or Sn?

Comment: Given that the previous sentence asks for the **total production** in the first 10 years, surely they are asking when Sn reaches 15000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They ask for $S_n$.

In situations like this, you can look at previous questions for clarity.

In questions "I" and "II," they ask for the production in the $1^{st}$ year and $12^{th} year$ which clearly mean $A_n$ because they ask specifically for those years.

In the question that you circled, they use the word "**total** production" meaning all the production combined up to that point. Otherwise, they would have followed the pattern of questions "I" and "II" in which they don't use the word "**total**".